# Upper bound Hölder norm of the solution to the non-linear PDE $\partial_t u (t, x) = \Delta_x \{ |\sigma (u (t, x))|^2 u(t, x) \}$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, regularity, heat-equation

We fix $T>0$ and let $\mathbb T := [0, T]$. Let $\sigma : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ belong to the Hölder space $C^{1, \alpha}_b (\mathbb R)$ for some $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. Let $u : \mathbb T \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R_+$ be the distributional solution to the non-linear PDE
$$
\partial_t u (t, x) = \Delta_x \{ |\sigma (u (t, x))|^2 u(t, x) \}.
$$

For brevity, let $u_t := u(t, \cdot)$. We assume that

- $u_0 \in C^\infty_b (\mathbb R^d)$ is a probability density function.
- there is $\lambda >0$ such that $\frac{1}{\lambda} \le \sigma \le \lambda$.

> Are there some estimates of $\| u_t \|_{C^{0, \beta}_b}$ in terms of $u_0$ and $\sigma$?

Any reference is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Could you clarify? 1. Did you mean $\sigma \in C_b^{1,\alpha}(\mathbb{R})$? 2. By $\sigma^2(u(t,x))$, do you mean $\sigma(\sigma(u(t,x)))$ or $(\sigma(u(t,x)))^2$?

Comment: @Fiktor Thank you for your comment! It is a typo and yess it should be $\sigma \in C_b^{1,\alpha}(\mathbb{R})$. By $\sigma^2(u(t,x))$, I meant $|\sigma(u(t,x))|^2$.

Comment: If you let $H(s) := s\sigma^2(s)$ then the equation takes the appealing form $\partial_t(H(u)) = H'(u)\Delta(H(u))$. If $H' > 0$ then standard uniformly parabolic theory (e.g. from the book of Lieberman) can be applied.